# Unable to highlight discrepancies reliably with the touchpad. Why is this happening?

Tags: ps-vita, papers-please

I'm trying to highlight discrepancies with the Vita touchpad, but it only works for less than a second so I have to smash it to get the "Interrogate" option to appear.

Why is this happening? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. For me it turned out to be an issue with the reVita plugin. Turning it off when playing papers please fixed the problem. If you have any plugins for things like remapping controls or such that may be affecting the touchscreen try disabling them.